# Unable to Retrieve Google ID Token in Flutter Web (Always Returns Null)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter web app where I'm unable to retrieve the Google ID token when using Google Sign-In. It consistently returns null, and I've tried various solutions but got no success. Here are my methods

```
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: <String>['email', 'openid'],
  );


  Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      googleSignIn.signOut();
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleUser != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
            await googleUser.authentication;

        final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );

        return await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      } else {
        print('No user');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error signing in with Google: $e");
      return null;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I checked my google console, OAuth key setup and a bunch of other stuffs but none of them worked. I'm starting to wonder if this issue is from the Flutter SDK itself and there is not solution yet.

Let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `googleSignIn.signIn()` no longer returns an idToken on web.
Switch over to `googlesignIn.signInSilently()`;

Here is an example

```dart
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    clientId: kIsWeb ? constants.WEB_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID : null,
    scopes: ['email', 'openid'],
  );

  GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  account ??= await googleSignIn.signIn();

  GoogleSignInAuthentication? auth;
  if (account != null) {
    auth = await account.authentication;
  }

  if (kIsWeb && account != null && auth?.idToken == null) {
    account = await googleSignIn.signInSilently(reAuthenticate: true);
    if (account != null) {
      auth = await account.authentication;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work plus the googleSignIn.signInSilently() method attempts to sign in the user silently - that is if the user is already signed in which in my case would limit the functionality